# Receive IPTV Streaming and Restream from Dedicated Debian Server

Tags: debian, streaming, iptv

I have a dedicated server *(Debian)* and i have an IPTV channel broadcast:

```
http://ex.example.com:8000/live/example/123456/85321.ts
```

I would like to take this stream and restream it from my server:

```
http://myserver.com:8000/live/myserver/myserver.ts
```

is that possible? if yes how can this be acheived?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Something as simple as Icecast with a simple per mount relay could suffice.

http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/relaying.html

This would make the unmodified bitstream available. If you want to modify the steam, then it becomes more complicated as you need to add another application to handle reencoding the steam.